# Python Beautiful Soup unwrap() not working as expected - want to extract content of a tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm new to working with Beautiful Soup and have problems understanding why `unwrap()` works the way it does in my case.

I have `python 3.6.9` and `beautifulsoup4 4.8.2`.

My input HTML is:

```
 html='''
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../common/style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="content">
       <h3  HEAD /h3>
          <div class="myclass">
          <br>
          MY TEXT
          <br>
         </div>
        <h3  HEAD2 /h3>
          <div class="myclass">
          <br>
          MY TEXT 2
          <br>
         </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    '''
```

And I want to get the content of the `div` with the `id` "content".
I figured this would be done by using `unwrap()`:

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')    
content=soup.find('div', {"id": "content"}).unwrap()
```

But this gives me the tag, without its contents:

`print(content):`

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

What happens here? How do I correctly extract the contents of the tag, without keeping the surrounding tag?

The output I expect is:

```
   <h3  HEAD /h3>
      <div class="myclass">
      <br>
      MY TEXT
      <br>
     </div>
    <h3  HEAD2 /h3>
      <div class="myclass">
      <br>
      MY TEXT 2
      <br>
     </div>
```

When using the approach with `.children` I have issues with escaping the tags, when appending to a BeautifulSoup object:

```
final_content=''.join([str(i) for i in content.children]) 
body.append(final_content)
```

This results in:

```
&lt;h3 head=""&gt;
&lt;div class="myclass"&gt;
&lt;br/&gt;
      MY TEXT
      &lt;br/&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;h3 head2=""&gt;
&lt;div class="myclass"&gt;
&lt;br/&gt;
      MY TEXT 2
      &lt;br/&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/h3&gt;&lt;/h3&gt;</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR: Print `soup`, not `content`**

I had the same problem and couldn't figure out why `unwrap()` doesn't return what I want it to. The reason is that it works a little differently than we expect.

`unwrap()` cleans the tag in the **initial soup** and returns the tag. Whatever contents we have saved in other variables using `soup.find()` will contain only the tags, without the content.

Comment: A couple of code examples would be useful, to illustrate what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

First, we edit your html so it actually works (problem was in h3 tag):

```
html='''
   <html>
   <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8"/>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../common/style.css"/>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div id="content">
      <h3>  HEAD </h3>
         <div class="myclass">
         <br>
         MY TEXT
         <br>
        </div>
       <h3>  HEAD2 </h3>
         <div class="myclass">
         <br>
         MY TEXT 2
         <br>
        </div>
   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
   '''
```

`unwrap()` removes the tag from your soup and puts its content inside the parent tag (if you check your soup again, there's no "content" id after running your code). So you should do something like:

```
content = soup.find('div', {"id": "content"})
content.contents[1:]
```

### Output:

```
<h3>  HEAD </h3>, '\n', <div class="myclass">
 <br/>
          MY TEXT
          <br/>
 </div>, '\n', <h3>  HEAD2 </h3>, '\n', <div class="myclass">
 <br/>
          MY TEXT 2
          <br/>
 </div>, '\n'
```

#### Alternative using `children` based on @KunduK's answer:

```
final_content = ''.join([str(i) for i in content.children])
```

### Output 2:

```
''.join([str(i) for i in content.children])
Out[96]: '\n<h3>  HEAD </h3>\n<div class="myclass">\n<br/>\n         MY TEXT\n         <br/>\n</div>\n<h3>  HEAD2 </h3>\n<div class="myclass">\n<br/>\n         MY TEXT 2\n         <br/>\n</div>\n'
```

Comment: That's not what I want. I want to remove the outer tag completely, not replace it

Comment: Maybe you should state your expected output in your question so we can better help you.

Comment: Seems your html isn't properly formatted, because it doesn't recognize your HEAD strings

Comment: Looks proper to me: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hn.asp

Comment: h3 tags were the problem, now I can do it

Comment: using 'content[1:]' gives 'TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice''

Comment: sorry it was `content.contents[1:]`

Comment: Nice answer, but the heading levels are a bit confusing in your answer. "Alternative using..." (currently level 3) should be higher than "Output 2:" (currently level 2 - the same as "Output:")

Answer (score 2):

Use `element.children` and then iterate.

```
html='''
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../common/style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="content">
       <h3>  HEAD </h3>
          <div class="myclass">
          <br>
          MY TEXT
          <br>
         </div>
        <h3>  HEAD2 </h3>
          <div class="myclass">
          <br>
          MY TEXT 2
          <br>
         </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    '''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
for item in soup.find('div',id='content').children:
     print(item)
```

**Output**:

```
<h3>  HEAD </h3>


<div class="myclass">
<br/>
          MY TEXT
          <br/>
</div>


<h3>  HEAD2 </h3>


<div class="myclass">
<br/>
          MY TEXT 2
          <br/>
</div>
```

---

Want to  get whole item in a variable then try it.

```
html='''
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../common/style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="content">
       <h3>  HEAD </h3>
          <div class="myclass">
          <br>
          MY TEXT
          <br>
         </div>
        <h3>  HEAD2 </h3>
          <div class="myclass">
          <br>
          MY TEXT 2
          <br>
         </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    '''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
str1=''
for item in soup.find('div',id='content').children:
    str1=str1+str(item)

print(str1)
```